# Images border-radius doesn't work during css transition

Tags: css, hover, blur, flicker

I'm using `border-radius: 50%;` to make an image round. By default the image is blurred and zoomed (with a hidden overflow) and on hover it will remove the blur and zoom. However, when I use a CSS transition on the element, it temporarily shows the overflow for the duration of the transition.

http://jsfiddle.net/jonny_me/cyvL61qx

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I believe on transition, the element gets taken out of document flow, something like a shadow `position: relative;` and put back in once the animation is complete.

If you force the `z-index` of the parent to be higher than that of the child, the parent should continue to clip the overflow.

http://jsfiddle.net/cyvL61qx/4/

```
figure.effect-park {
    background-color: #0D4C16;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
}

figure.effect-park img {
    z-index: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-filter: blur(1.5px);
    filter: blur(1.5px);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
    transform: scale(1.15);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s, -webkit-transform 0.2s;
    transition: opacity 0.2s, transform 0.2s;
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. `position:relative` and higher `z-index` on the parent solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: That actually helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Just make border-radius inherit

```
.parent {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.parent img {
    border-radius: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Putting this css on the parent worked for me:

```
clip-path: circle(50% at center);
-webkit-clip-path: circle(50% at center);
```

tested on safari, firefox and chrome on mac and microsoft edge.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an element growing with right corners while transitioning and once the transition is at end the round corners reappeared. I tried all the above solutions without success (except the clip-path because edge or IE don't support it).

Then I removed my filter and the transform worked. So my solution is to remove the filter to get it working at least with the zoom.

Answer (score 0):

While debug-in I noticed that the problem disappeared when adding an `outline`, so I've just added a transparent one, but I'm not sure why it  worked.

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/eloyesp/pen/BaxwzLa) to show it working. (hover on the images, the last one is working)