# Polymer 1.2.4 paper-progress and iron-image have crazy border-radius

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer-1.0

In my Polymer-Webapp I found a crazy behaviour of an `iron-image` with a `border-radius`. May anybody tell me what is happening here?

As you may see in the example below, the `iron-image` should have a rounded border (set via css). But as long as the `paper-progress` is not hidden, that rounded border is gone. To show that behaviour, you may toggle the visibility of the `paper-progress` in the example. How can I avoid this behaviour?

```css
#round {
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  
  <base href="http://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="import" href="paper-progress/paper-progress.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-image/iron-image.html">
</head>
<body>
  <paper-progress id="progress" indeterminate> </paper-progress>
  <paper-button raised onclick="document.querySelector('#progress').hidden=!document.querySelector('#progress').hidden">Toggle Progress</paper-button>
  <iron-image sizing="contain" id="round" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/25/Red.svg/2000px-Red.svg.png"></iron-image>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working by just setting a `z-index` on the `iron-image` (according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934887/images-border-radius-doesnt-work-during-css-transition)).

Comment: this is not a fix it will cause issue to polymer design image will display when you scroll the menu.