# CSS Transition with Border Radius and Linear Gradient

Tags: css, border, css-transitions, linear-gradients

Given my CodePen https://codepen.io/scottmgerstl/pen/MpMeBy this is my image layout in question

```
<span class="profile-pic-wrapper">
    <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
        <img class="profile-pic" src="http://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/article/67689-image/Video-shows-Super-Mario-64-HD-playing-on-the-Apple-iPhone-6.jpg"/>
        <span class="profile-pic-overlay">
            <span class="social-icon">View Profile</span>
        </span>
     </a>
</span>
```

**Description**

I am trying to use a CSS transition on a linear gradient (`profile-pic-overlay`) that is clipped by a border radius (`profile-pic-wrapper`). The desired behavior is to have a profile image when, the rounded image container is hovered over, a linear gradient fades into view indicating you can view the profile.

**The issue**

The gradient does not honor the bounds of the border radius. I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934887/images-border-radius-doesnt-work-during-css-transition) but when I do that, the linear gradient will not transition. @Keyframe animation doesn't help either.

Any ideas?

**Edit**

This appears to be an issue only with Chrome on Windows

Comment: Looks fine to me on Chrome - MAC ... can you include your browser ?

Comment: I'm on Chrome on windows

Comment: A tip  change the transition from the `:hover` to the normal state taht way you have the transition on both mouse leave and enter https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qrzaay

Comment: Good idea. Let me know if you have any ideas for the clipping issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I can test the problem is related to the `<a>` container of your gradient layer. Searching about how to solve this issue here are some properties you can add that will cover most browsers:

[`will-change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/will-change) & [`transform:translate3d`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate3d)

Add this to your code:

```
.profile-pic-wrapper, .profile-pic-wrapper a {
  display:block;
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
  will-change:transform;
}
```

#### [Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qrzaay)

---

<sub>**Note:** Info adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16681137/2887133), I want to post here my answer to suit your case beacuse you need to do it on a tag and parent tag, but if you want we can close it as dup.</sub>