# Why does my transform: translateY flicker in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, css, transform, css-multicolumn-layout

I have a simple multi-column layout; I'm trying to lift an element on `:hover` using `translateY`.

It causes flickering (tested on Chrome 57). How do I fix this?

```js
"use strict";

$(function () {
  var $target = $('.wall');

  function getImageUrl(id) {
    var width = 500;
    var height = 250 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 150);
    return "https://unsplash.it/" + width + "/" + height + "?image=" + id;
  }

  function addElement(element) {
    var $template = $target.find('.template').clone().appendTo($target).removeClass("template");

    $template.find("a").attr("href", element.post_url);

    $template.find("img").attr("src", getImageUrl(element.id));

    $template.find("figcaption").text(element.author);

    $template.removeClass("hide");
  }

  $.getJSON("https://unsplash.it/list", function (data) {
    var images = 12;
    var elements = [];

    function getRandomImage() {
      var id = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length);
      return data.splice(id, 1)[0];
    }

    while (images > elements.length) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(1)){break;}
      elements.push(getRandomImage());
    }
window.CP.exitedLoop(1);


    elements.forEach(function (element) {
      addElement(element);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.wall {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
     -moz-column-count: 3;
          column-count: 3;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
}
.wall * {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
     page-break-inside: avoid;
          break-inside: avoid;
}
.wall .brick {
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
.wall .brick a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: inherit;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 333ms ease;
  transition: -webkit-transform 333ms ease;
  transition: transform 333ms ease;
  transition: transform 333ms ease, -webkit-transform 333ms ease;
}
.wall .brick a:hover, .wall .brick a:focus {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-1rem);
          transform: translateY(-1rem);
}
.wall .brick .thumbnail {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
.wall .brick figcaption {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wall column">
  <div class="hide brick template">
    <a>
      <figure>
        <img class="thumbnail" /><figcaption></figcaption>
      </figure>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/Tymek/pen/zwGbGp)

Comment: It might be interesting to note that for me (Safari 10.1) only the middle and right picture of the top row flicker, the other images move back and forth as intended.

Comment: Since Chrome is also Webkit, this might solve your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946748/iphone-webkit-css-animations-cause-flicker

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751012/css-transform-causes-flicker-in-safari-but-only-when-the-browser-is-2000px-w) is also similar. Did you look at [these Google results](https://www.google.nl/#q=css+transform+flicker) yet? Many seem applicable.

Comment: Try adding `will-change:transform;`  to your a element http://stackoverflow.com/a/43281723/2887133 ... seems to work https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qmdGRj

Comment: @DaniP Safari simply stops rendering the two images that flickered before after adding the `will-change`.

Comment: Seems fine to me on Safari too ...

Comment: Thank you comments! Those suggestions helped. If one of you would like to post it as an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Placing the following code in the element with the transform property should solve:

```
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

In your case:

```
a {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: transform 333ms ease;
  &:hover, &:focus {
    transform: translateY(-1rem);
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

Comment: Same fix works with the new bootstrap 4 card-deck as well!